# Using Never types in an interface, throwing errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some code here and the IDE is throwing me an error on the NEVER type fields. I am not quite sure what I should do to satisfy this IDE. I set the isAnonymous field to false so I assume that I should leave the primaryIdentityHas and primiaryIdentitySpace both empty but when I do that it's complaining that I am missing those fields. Can someone please provide me some insight to this?

```
export const getOneDSCoreFieldsUnAuth = (
context: TelemetryLoggerContext,
): CoreFields => {
return {
    app: {
        name: context.appName,
        platform: '',
        version: '1',
    },
    session: {
        id: context.correlationId,
    },
        user: {
            isAnonymous: true,
        },
    };
};

export declare namespace User {
interface Contract {
    primaryIdentityHash?: string;
    primaryIdentitySpace?: string;
    tenantId?: string;
    tenantGroup?: string;
    isAnonymous?: boolean;
}
type StrictContractKnownUser = {
    primaryIdentityHash: string;
    primaryIdentitySpace: PrimaryIdentitySpace;
    tenantId?: string;
    tenantGroup?: string;
    isAnonymous?: false;
};
type StrictContractUnknownUser = {
    primaryIdentityHash: never;
    primaryIdentitySpace: never;
    tenantId?: never;
    tenantGroup?: never;
    isAnonymous: true;
};
type StrictContract = StrictContractKnownUser | StrictContractUnknownUser;
}
```

I am getting the error message below.

> Type '{ isAnonymous: true; }' is not assignable to type 'StrictContract'.
> Type '{ isAnonymous: true; }' is missing the following properties from type 'StrictContractUnknownUser': primaryIdentityHash, primaryIdentitySpacets(2322)
> DataModels.d.ts(193, 5): The expected type comes from property 'user' which is declared here on type 'CoreFields'

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] that we can paste into a standalone IDE to see what you're seeing without unrelated errors; if `TelemetryLoggerContext`, `CoreFields`, and `PrimaryIdentitySpace` are vital to the question then we need their definitions; if not, you should probably replace them with something else, so we can focus on your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

`never` is a type which means "nothing can be assigned to this" (not even undefined or null). You have a required property to which you can't ever assign any value - this cannot be satisfied.

One solution might be to require that they be never and optional, which will result in an error if you try to use an object which is both `isAnonymous` and passes values for the never fields:

```js
type StrictContractUnknownUser = {
  primaryIdentityHash?: never,
  primaryIdentitySpace?: never,
  tenantId?: never,
  tenantGroup?: never
  isAnonymous: true
}
```

Or, for functionally the same thing, you could simply omit them from the type:

```
type StrictContractUnknownUser = {
    isAnonymous: true
}
```

Comment: the only thing I can edit is the getOneDSCoreFieldsUnAuth  Function, all else is in a library.

Comment: That type is literally unusable then. You should file a ticket with the library maintainer. You can add your own typing overrides in the meantime to fix it in your project. I suggest making them optional `never` properties.